# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I get mongoose error every time I try to check my if condition (project== null). Please see the code below:

```
var IssueSchema= new Schema ({

    issue_description: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 500,
        required: true

    },
    issue_status: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255,
        default: "Open"
    },
    issue_priority: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    },
    deadline:{
        type: Date
    },
},
    {timestamps:true});

var Project= new Schema ({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 5,
        max: 255

    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 500      
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    },
    priority: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    },
    progress: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    } , 
    issues: [IssueSchema],
    risks: [RiskSchema],
    _user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}, {timestamps:true});
```

The code:

controller

```
        Project.findById({_id:req.params.projectId}, (err,project) => {
            console.log(project);
            if (project == null) {
              err= new ErrorHandler(404, "Project not found");
              return next (err);
            }   
             else {
                project.issues.push(req.body);
                project.save();
                res.status(200).send('Issue created');}

            }
        )};
```

router

```
projectRouter.route ('/:projectId/issues')

.post(issueController.createIssue)
```

It works fine if I enter the right projected. But I want to handle the case when the specified projectID doesn't exist. When I enter some random projectID in the URL parameter it is throwing : `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "123" at path "_id" for model "Project"`.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the issue with the condition `project== null`, here in this case your query isn't even getting fired from code to DB.

**Issue :**

So mongoose `.findById()` will take in a valid string value & internally convert it to type `ObjectId()`.

If you pass in a string `5eb78994dbb89024f04a2507` to `.findById()` then mongoose internally does something like this `.findOne({_id : ObjectId('5eb78994dbb89024f04a2507')})`.

When I say *valid* string you need to understand a string value inside an `ObjectId()` has to be of certain form, Check this : [MongoDB-ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

If you pass in `123` which is not a valid string for `ObjectId()` mongoose if failing to convert to `ObjectId()` and throwing that error even prior to forming your query.

So to test your scenario, if your actual string is something like this `5eb78994dbb89024f04a2507` just tweak it with changing last value like `5eb78994dbb89024f04a2508` and give it a try or you can get a sample from above provided link or from another collection's doc in your DB.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! it's clear now. so, in this case, I assume it's ok for the server to respond with 500? Or is there any other proper way of handling this?

Comment: @DiVa : Discussion on Http error codes will be broad range ! Few people will give 200 OK with an error message & a custom error code in body (Vs) few will choose to give some different http error code apart from 500. Few say 500 is very general & is mostly for any unexpected failures but not for business use cases failures, You can think of it this way, this can be a request validation failure so you can send 400 (bad request) & a custom message in body ! Finally, it all depends on your team & project setup..

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, so I replaced `findByIdandUpdate`  to `findOneAndUpdate`

Replacing following code

```
Profile.findByIdAndUpdate  (
          { user: req.user.id },
          { $set: profileFields },
          { new: true }
        ) .then((profile) => res.json(profile))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

with

```
Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: req.user.id },
          { $set: profileFields },
          { new: true }
        ) .then((profile) => res.json(profile))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

works charm